# How to do subset sum with state-space tree?

Tags: backtracking

I can't implement the State-space tree. How to implement it for subset sum problem?

Please tell the idea to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your effort also with some code.. what you want here? pseudo  code or code in some language? stackoverflow is to help someone when they face problem in programming. you can get idea with search also.

Comment: Have you tried searching for it on Stack Overflow? There are many results on the subset sum problem for many different programming languages. Also it may help to specify if want to understand the general concept or an implementation in a specific language.

Comment: Sir, I have a set of positive integers. I have to tell if there any subset of S that all elements summation equal to given sum. I have done it with DP with O(sum*n) complexity. But here sum can be 10^9. So what's will be the approach?
n>=30 and sum>=10^9

Comment: backtracking is not gonna get you anywhere as it will have O(2^n) complexity. you can try using map or set instead of array to store already calculated sums. they will help in avoiding a lot of useless comparisions that  are done when array is used.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks.